# Can't push after using pop

Tags: c, stack

I've been at this for about 7 hours trying to get this to work on my own, but I can't figure it out. With my testing earlier I was able to successfully fully push all the values of my char[] into the stack and I could properly pop them off and return the value.
However, if I try to push something back onto the stack then the whole program crashes.

Notes:

- The code is supposed to be used to create nodes for an Expression Tree later on
- The commented out code in the switch statement is code that I had when the error occurred, was just saving it for when I could have fixed it.

-When pushing after using a pop, the function is properly called, however it does not enter either the if or the else statement within push.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Stack;
typedef struct StackNode;
typedef struct StackPtr;


struct StackPtr
{
    struct StackPtr *prev;
    struct StackNode *ptr;
};

struct StackNode
{
    char c;
    struct StackNode *lchild;
    struct StackNode *rchild;
};

struct Stack
{
    struct StackPtr *top;
};

// Prototypes

void initStack(struct Stack*);
struct StackNode* createNode(char);
struct StackNode* pop(struct Stack*);
void push(struct Stack*, struct StackNode*);
int isEmpty(struct Stack*);




int main()
{
    struct Stack *s = malloc(sizeof(s));
    initStack(s);
    char exp[7] = "45+67+*";
    int length = 0;

    for(length; length<3; length++) // push the expression onto the stack
    {
        struct StackNode *exp1 = malloc(sizeof(exp1));
        struct StackNode *exp2 = malloc(sizeof(exp2));
        struct StackNode *c = malloc(sizeof(c));

        if(exp[length] > 47 && exp[length] < 58) // is a number
        {
            c->c = exp[length];
            push(s,c);
        }

        else
        {
            switch(exp[length])
            {
            default:
                printf("exp[length] error\n");
                break;
            case '+':
                exp2 = pop(s);
                exp1 = pop(s);

                c->c = '7';
                push(s, c);
                //push(s, exp1->ptr);
                //push(s, exp2->ptr);
                //c->c = exp[length];
                //c->rchild = exp2;
                //c->lchild = exp1;
                //printf("test ");
                //push(s, c);
                //printf("test ");
                break;
            case '-':
                break;
            case '*':
                break;
            case '/':
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void initStack(struct Stack *s)
{
    struct StackNode *n = malloc(sizeof(n));
    struct StackPtr *p = malloc(sizeof(p));

    n->c = NULL;
    n->lchild = NULL;
    n->rchild = NULL;
    p->prev = NULL;
    p->ptr = n;
    s->top = p;
}

struct StackNode* createNode(char c)
{
    struct StackNode *n = malloc(sizeof(n));
    n->c = c;
    n->lchild = NULL;
    n->rchild = NULL;
    return n;
}

void push(struct Stack *s, struct StackNode *n)
{
    if(s->top->ptr->c == NULL) // First item being pushed
    {
        s->top->ptr = n;
        printf("1Added: %c to the stack\n", n->c);
    }
    else
    {
        struct StackPtr *o = malloc(sizeof(o));
        o->prev = s->top;
        s->top = o;
        s->top->ptr = n;
        printf("2Added: %c to the stack\n", n->c);
    }
}

struct StackNode* pop(struct Stack *s)
{
    if(isEmpty(s) == 1)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty!\n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        struct StackPtr *tmp = malloc(sizeof(tmp));
        tmp = s->top;
        s->top = s->top->prev;
        printf("Popped: %c from the stack.\n",tmp->ptr->c);
        return tmp->ptr;
    }
}


int isEmpty(struct Stack *s)
{
    if(s->top == NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0; // false
```

Comment: pop() looks very suspicious.  To start with, you malloc tmp and then overwrite it in the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `POP` function is setting

```
       s->top = s->top->prev;
```

after two nodes are popped out the Prev value is NULL so top is pointing to NULL, which is causing the segmentation fault during the next `PUSH`

Few more things to consider, change value to 8 instead of 7 as \0 needs to be fit. or use it as
char exp[]

```
       char exp[8] = "45+67+*";
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Also thanks for explaining it rather than just saying how it should be. I'll mark it as the right answer in a few once I get it going. Thanks again!